# flashbuilder, must restart to rebuild swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

Some of my FB4.7 projects require I restart them in order to rebuild my SWFs. This problem has been infuriating me for months if not years.

I've logged the solution below.

Comment: I don't know how to properly write self-answers, but I know that the question should be formed as a question, and your answer should then explain what the future visitor has to do in order to fix their problem, if it matches yours. Please rephrase the question to make it sound more like a question. You can also remove the word "Solution" out of the title.

Comment: hope this is a bit better

Answer (score 0):

Windows Search Indexing was to blame! You need to disable search for your project folders.

Control Panel -> Indexing Options -> Modify -> and then deselect your project folders folders (I had to first click on 'Users' within the 'Summary of selected locations' box, and then navigated to my project folders and deselected them in the 'change selected locations' box).